# data is not passing in vue template although the json array is in vue page

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using axios to get data from laravel API. I am getting the API data in my corresponding vue page (in created() hook), but it's not passing into the template. I am sharing the console Image here :

[image]

My codes from vue are :

```
export default {
    name : "employee-list",

    data() {
        return{
            employee_list : []
        }
    },

    async created() {
        const res = await axios.get('/employees-list')
        if(res.status == 200){
            console.log(res.data)
           this.employee_list = res.data
        }else{
           console.log('something went wrong')
        }
    }
}
```

My Template table :

```
<table class="employee-list">
    <tr>
        <td>Full Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
        <td>Designation</td>
        <td>Loans</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
        <td>Joining Date</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Photo</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="(employee, i) in employee_list" :key="i">
        <td>{{employee.full_name}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.email}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.designation}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.loans}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.joining_date}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.address}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.photo}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.status}}</td>
        <td><button :id="employee.id">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I also tried with callApi() method, But it says "this.callApi is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a double array in res.data, instead of one, thats why you see one row without data

Comment: Thanks lol, I completely missed that. I will mark your answer as accepted  in 5 min, thanks